# Laser printer cardridge has a plastic foil

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I have a color laser printer Samsung CLP-365. I noticed that yellow is showing signs of low supply, roller is not entirely covered in powder, showing lines. Perhaps this is simply due to higher usage of this color but I noticed **there is a plastic foil that wasnt peeled off. Is it supposed to be there?** Other cardridges do not have such a foil. I am wondering if this foil is scrubbing powder off and therefore waste it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recieved a reply from the company that sold the printer. They say that the foil is necessary and removal will effectively damage it. Was attached by the producer.